# Cannot allocate memory error on checkout page

Tags: php, apache, memory-management, opencart

We're using Opencard 1.5.6. On checkout, an alert of 500 Internal Server Error randomly generates. Please refer to screen shot provided:

[image: screen shot of error alert]

I've checked the Cpanel error log and noticed:

```
[Thu Jul 17 09:26:17 2014] [error] [client 000.000.0.000] File does not exist: /home/example/public_html/500.shtml, referer: http://www.example.com.ph/index.php?route=quickcheckout/checkout
[Thu Jul 17 09:26:17 2014] [error] [client 000.000.0.000] (12)Cannot allocate memory: couldn't create child process: /opt/suphp/sbin/suphp for /home/example/public_html/index.php, referer: http://www.example.com.ph/index.php?route=quickcheckout/checkout
```

The .htaccess is blank, while the php.ini code is:

```
magic_quotes_gpc = Off;
register_globals = Off;
default_charset = UTF-8;
memory_limit = 64M;
max_execution_time = 36000;
upload_max_filesize = 999M;
safe_mode = Off;
mysql.connect_timeout = 20;
session.use_cookies = On;
session.use_trans_sid = Off;
session.gc_maxlifetime = 172800;
allow_url_fopen = on;
;display_errors = 1;
;error_reporting = E_ALL;
default_socket_timeout =300;
extension=php_openssl.dll;
extension=php_mcrypt.dll;
```

Any ideas how to solve this problem?

Thank you,

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21104175/342740

Comment: I've checked the cpanel Resource Usage Logs and sofar, we are nowhere near the limit: CPU Usage 0% out of 100%, I/O Usage, 0 out of 1024, Entry Processes 0 out of 20, Number of Processes 0 out of 100, Physical Memory Usage 11.66M out of 1.00G, Virtual Memory Usage 0.00k out of 1.00G

Comment: If you are in hurry then I suggest you to hire a sysadmin to take a look for you.

Comment: Have you checked your tmp directory to see if its full

Comment: The cart is on shared hosting. I've consulted with the tech support and was advised that there is no limit to out /tmp directory. I've checked with the cpanel resource monitoring, and saw instances where virtual memory reached its limit. If this is the cause of the error, I wonder how we can optimize the codes in OpenCart.